# Subversion subdomain Digest authentication shows blank page as response

Tags: ubuntu, svn, apache-2.2, mod-dav-svn, http-authentication

I'm trying to configure my subversion server using apache2, mod_dav_svn and a basically digest authenticaton (for now). I've setup the subdomain svn.example.com to serve the repos and created the virtualhost conf like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName svn.example.com

    <Location />
            DAV svn

            # Automatically map any "/foo" URL to repository /var/svn/repos/foo
            SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos

            # List repositories if viewed from a web browser
            SVNListParentPath on

            # Authentication: Digest
            AuthName "Private Area"
            AuthType Digest
            AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth.htdigest

            # Authoriztion: Authenticated users only
            Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This conf file (svn.example.com) resides inside apache2's `sites-available` directory, as well inside `sites-enabled`.

The last thing, I created the auth user file using htdigest.

At this step I wanted to test the setup. But each time I open svn.example.com in a browser all I get is a blank page. I don't know what is wrong. I checked the apache access/error log files, but there's nothing there that could help.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what it was. First of all I had an error in my file zone, instead of a CNAME entry for the subdomain, there was an A record.

After that, I enabled the auth_digest module and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there must be something in the `error_log`. Make sure that Apache has access permission on the SVN root directory:

```
# chown -R www-data:www-data /var/svn/repos
```

Comment: I already chowned the repos directory with that user/group. In error_log there are only notices from when I restarted apache. Nothing else.

Comment: Test Apache syntax `apachectl configtest`, set `LogLevel` to `debug` and add a `ErrorLog` directive for your virtual host, reproduce this problem to see if you have something in log file.

Comment: `configtest` says Syntax is OK. I added `debug` LogLevel and ErrorLog and the only lines in error.log are `[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down` and `[notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.12 configured -- resuming normal operations`. If it matters, I commented the lines with authentication and authorization but nothing changed :|. I don't know, could be something with apache ? It's a fresh install, maybe I forgot to configure something properly.
`